# How to use custom font in email template

Tags: css, email, fonts, html-email, inline

I want to use customs fonts in email templates but why @font-face style is not supported by most of the mail providers

what to do now?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[**`@font-face` is not supported in *some* email clients**](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/webfonts/), but not all. Depending on what fonts you're designing with, you could specify a font-stack the starts with a custom font and falls back to similar system fonts. Something like:

```
font-family: 'open sans', 'helvetica neue', sans-serif;
```

The email won't match pixel perfect in every email client, but does it have to? [More info on email typography, web fonts, and fallbacks](https://litmus.com/blog/typography-tips-for-email-designers).

You can make an image of each text blog as Jeff suggests, but it's not a great solution that needs to scale.

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed the font in an image and use the image instead of the font. Or you have to choose a web-safe font.  You can use @font-face but currently it is only widely supported in iOS/Apple Mail.

Comment: how i can embed font with inline css?because in email template should be use  only inline css